# Mongo Update Record With Values Set In the Same Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following code for an API that aims to update a document in Mongo. It uses `collection.update` to insert values into a section and then another `collection.update` to push these values into an array within the document.

However, when I run this code, I keep getting `nan` in `events.eventTime` and `events.endDate = null`. How can I modify this to work properly? That is, I first insert values into `runtime.` and subsequently use those to push into `events` array.

```
router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    //Important to use findOne here to get an object back instead of an array
    collection.findOne({_id : req.params.id }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
        //console.log(activity);

        collection.update({
            _id: activity._id
        },
        {
            $set: {
                    "runtime.started": false,
                    "runtime.endDate": new Date()
            } 
        },
        function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.json(activity);
            console.log(activity);
        }
        );

        collection.update({
            _id: activity._id
        },
        {
            $push: {events: {
                        eventTime: ((activity.runtime.endDate - activity.runtime.startDate) / 1000),
                        startDate: activity.runtime.startDate,
                        endDate: activity.runtime.endDate
                    }
                }, 
        },
        function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.json(activity);
            console.log(activity);
        }
        );

    });
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your runtime.endDate and runtime.startDate values?

Comment: See images attached.

Comment: Are you sure that subtraction will work for you?

Comment: Subtraction is not the problem. The problem is that `endDate` is not being moved to the array as I intend it.

Comment: are you getting endDate value in `activity` result?

Comment: The `console.log(activity)` output returns 1. I am not sure what that means. Perhaps that is the Express' way of saying that the update is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess either you should use promise or nested callback, javascript is asynchronous, so even though it looks like the second update call will be called after first, in reality they are being called at the same time and thus I guess the weird behavior.

It's better to wrap your DB call in promise and apply chaining. maybe you want to look at $q promises which is impressive. If you don't want to use promises, then call the second update method inside the function of the first update call

```
router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    //Important to use findOne here to get an object back instead of an array
    collection.findOne({_id : req.params.id }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
        //console.log(activity);

        collection.update({
            _id: activity._id
        },
        {
            $set: {
                    "runtime.started": false,
                    "runtime.endDate": new Date()
            } 
        },
        function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.json(activity);
            console.log(activity);
            collection.update({
             _id: activity._id
            },
            {
             $push: {events: {
                        eventTime: ((activity.runtime.endDate - activity.runtime.startDate) / 1000),
                        startDate: activity.runtime.startDate,
                        endDate: activity.runtime.endDate
                    }
                }, 
        },
        function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.json(activity);
            console.log(activity);
        }
        );
        }
        );

    }); });
```

Yes looks pretty messy, that's why promises are good.

Update, maybe you can try merging both the update call into one

```
collection.findOne({_id : req.params.id }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
        //console.log(activity);
         var date  = new Date();
         var duration = (date - activity.runtime.startDate)/1000;
        collection.update({
            _id: activity._id
        },
        {
            $set: {
                    "runtime.started": false,
                    "runtime.endDate": date
            },
            $push: {events: {
                        eventTime: duration,
                        startDate: activity.runtime.startDate,
                        endDate: date
                    }
                }
        },
        function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.json(activity);
            console.log(activity);
    });

});
```

Comment: How would you go about using a promise? Is it a much better way or just simply an alternative?

Comment: Also, I have tried something similar yesterday to no avail. In fact, I copied your code and it still produces `runtime.endDate = null` when I look inside Mongo.

Comment: Not only much better, they are much preferred way for any I/O calls, either DB or reading files etc. you can start with a simple examples from https://www.npmjs.com/package/q . The way I would prefer is that wrap all your db calls in promises in a module and then apply chaining by calling those wrapped methods. Promises are great and saves you headache once you get used to them.

Comment: Okay I am little confused now, the image in your question shows that in event endDate you get null, in comment you are saying runtime.endDate is null. if runtime.endDate is null, it surely means that eventTime will be nan because you cant use mathematics operators on null.

Comment: My fault. I mean that `events.endDate = null`, while the `runtime.endDate` still has the proper non-null value.

Comment: you are using console.log(activity) in both the update call, by comparing them you can get some clue. for example. first console should show all the values correctly and second one should show the incorrect values.

Comment: Here is what I get `activity from $set: 1
activity from $push: 1` It does not return the full object, but only number 1.

Comment: Well then doesn't it make sense, in the second update you are using activity (activity.runtime.endDate) but your console shows your activity is 1 and no more an object which you were expecting hence those nan and null. I think you can merge both of the update in one update call.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Actually, that was my first attempt. When I do that, there is still `events.endDate = null`. The only difference is that `events.eventTime = -1474919620.937`. That is, it is able to do the subtraction somehow.

Comment: that's weird, I think the updated answer of merging should work, I am convinced that two updates are not working because you are using activity variable which is stale.

Comment: It seems to work every other time or something like that. Sometimes there is `events.eventTime = nan` yet others it has a meaningful value. The other fields are always transferred successfully.

Comment: maybe you need to put activity.runtime.startDate in console and see if you are getting correct value each time, otherwise I don't see any other issue.

Comment: I did. It turns out that whenever there is `NaN`, the `activity.runtime.startDate` is somehow read as a string, while it is always of Date type in DB. I am not sure why that happens. Is it possible for the same variable to be interpreted as two different types?

Comment: That's unlikely, I think sometime runtime.startDate  is being updated as String, while other time it's updated as date, you may need to check all the points where your startDate is being updated. even in the image in your question, it's showing startDate as string.

Comment: I am actually beginning to suspect that it is some kind of a glitch with the Mongo driver or Mongo itself because sometimes it is written as String and others as Date. The same happens with the other field. Now, the calculation proceeds successfully only when they are the same.